# At least one True value per column in numpy boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, boolean-operations

Suppose I have a very big 2D boolean array (for the sake of the example, let's take dimensions 4 lines x 3 columns):

```
toto = np.array([[True, True, False],
                [False, True, False],
                [True, False, False],
                [False, True, False]])
```

I want to transform `toto`so that it contains at least one True value per column , by leaving other columns untouched.

EDIT : The rule is just this : If a column is all False, I want to introduce a True in a random line.

So in this example, one of the False in the 3rd column should become True.

How would you do that efficiently?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what's the desired output? one would say you could set the first row to True and your problems are solved

Comment: In order to know how to help you best, what have you tired so far, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
col_mask = ~np.any(toto, axis=0)
row_idx = np.random.randint(toto.shape[0], size=np.sum(col_mask))
toto[row_idx, col_mask]=True
```

`col_mask` is `array([False, False,  True])` of changeable columns.
`row_idx` is array that consists of changeable indexes of rows.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

toto = np.array([[False, True, False], [False, True, False],
                 [False, False, False], [False, True, False]])

# First we get a boolean array indicating columns that have at least one True value
mask = np.any(toto, axis=0)

# Now we invert the mask to get columns indexes (as boolean array) with no True value
mask = np.logical_not(mask)

# Notice that if we index with this mask on the colum dimension we get elements
# in all rows only in the columns containing no True value. The dimension is is
# "num_rows x num_columns_without_true"
toto[:, mask]

# Now we need random indexes for rows in the columns containing only false. That
# means an array of integers from zero to `num_rows - 1` with
# `num_columns_without_true` elements
row_indexes = np.random.randint(toto.shape[0], size=np.sum(mask))

# Now we can use both masks to select one False element in each column containing only False elements and set them to True
toto[row_indexes, mask] = True
```

---

Disclaimer: mathfux was faster with essentially the same solution as the one I was writing (accept his answer then if this is what you were looking for), but since I was writting with more comments I decided to post anyway.